# How to prove that if $S\subset \mathbb{Z}$ has a supremum $a$, then $a\in S?$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, supremum-and-infimum

This question came up in my undergraduate intro to Real Analysis class. We are given that $\mathbb{R}$ is a complete ordered field, and $\mathbb{Z}$ is a subset of the set $\mathbb{R}$.

I don't really know where to start. I thought of starting from the definition of integers, but we haven't been given one. I tried to make up a definition and the best I can think of is $\{1, 1+1, 1+1+1, ...\} \cup \{-1, -1 + (-1), -1 + (-1) + (-1),...\}$, but I'm not sure of how to make it more formal.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is totally disconnected.

Comment: @anomaly What do you mean by that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_disconnected_space

Comment: Well, not a definition but a properties that you can take as a given: i) 1 is an integer.  ii) if $n$ is an integer if and only if $n+1$ is an integer.  iii) there are no integers in the open interval (0,1).  The important thing here is that if $n$ is an integer there is an interval (n-d,n+e) in which $n$ is the only integer.  So if $s$ is sup then there must be an integer in S in (s-d,s] no matter how small d.  That can only happen if s itself is the integer that is in S.

Comment: @anomaly: $\Bbb{Q}$ is totally disconnected too, but it isn't closed under taking suprema. The relevant order-theoretic fact here is that the ordering on $\Bbb{Z}$ is discrete (but I think the OP is looking for a more concrete explanation, e.g., as provided in Alfred Yerger's answer below).

Comment: @RobArthan: Well, yes. I was trying to get the OP to start out by taking a small ball around $a$, and discrete would have been a better hint for it.

Answer (score 3):

If the supremum $S$ of a set of integers $X$ was not itself an integer, there is an integer below $S$ written as $\lfloor S \rfloor$ and an integer above $S$ written $\lceil S \rceil$. Note that $\lfloor S \rfloor$ is the maximal element in $X$, because $S$ is a sup. Also, since $S$ is not an integer, $S - \lfloor S \rfloor > 0$. Now the supremum of a set $X$ has the property that for every $\epsilon > 0$, $S - \epsilon$ is not an upper bound for $X$, since $S$ is the least upper bound. But if we take $\epsilon = \frac{S - \lfloor S \rfloor}{2}$, then $S - \epsilon$ is still an upper bound.

This shows that $S$ has to actually be an integer, and in particular, it has to belong to $X$. Notice that there is nothing special about the integers here, and this in fact is true fr any discrete set of points on the real line.

Comment: Your last sentence is not true. The set $$\left\{1-\frac{1}{n} \; | \; n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$$ is discrete on the real line, but it does not have maximum. You must also require that your discrete subset is *closed* in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hmmm.... I'm not sure the meaning of the term "discrete" would be universally understood in this context.

Comment: For a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, "discrete" usually means that the induced topology is the discrete one. Honestly, I do not see other meanings here.

Comment: We can clarify the statement in the answer by specifying _uniform_ discreteness.

Comment: Yes, you need some condition ensuring that the points of your discrete subspace do not accumulate somewhere.

Comment: "For a subset of R, "discrete" usually means that the induced topology is the discrete one."  Really?  I think it more commonly means one in which each point has a neighborhood that contains no other points of the set.  As it does here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteSet.html

Comment: It is obviously the same thing :-)

Comment: Oh, I thought I was responding to the person who claimed $\{1 - 1/n\}$ was not discrete.  Sorry.  That comment has since been deleted.

Comment: Actually, I really do not see how $\{1 - 1/n\}$ can be viewed as not discrete.

Comment: Hmm I am trying to extract the proprety of the integers that made the proof work. I *think* this proprety is that any subset of integers contains a maximal element. Is this right, and if so, can it be proved somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $s = \sup S$ is a real number.  There is some integer $n$ so that $n-1 < s \le n$.

Let $d$ be so that $n-1 < d < s$.  By definition of least upper bound $d$ is not an upper bound.

So there exists a $t \in S$ so that $ d < t \le s$.  So $n-1 < d < t \le s \le n$.  But $t$ is an integer.  And $n-1 < t \le n$.

The only way that is possible is if $t = n$.

So $n = t \le s \le n$.

The only way that is possible is if $n = t = s$.  So $s = t \in S$.

=====

Note: this all hinges on knowing i) for any real number $s$ there is an integer $n$ so that $n < s \le n+1$.

and ii) for any two real numbers $a, b$ so that $a < b$, there exists a real number $d$ so that $a < d < b$.

and iii) that for any integer $n$ there is not integer between $n$ and $n+1$.

1 and 20 are the Archimedean property.  They are very basic but actually must be proven in a basic analysis course.  3) is ... well, it depends on your axioms and definitions.

===== take 2 ====

> . I thought of starting from the definition of integers, but we haven't been given one.

That's actually a problem.  I think the *single* aspect of integers you should take as a given is that if $n$ is an integer then $n$ is the only integer within the open interval $(n-1, n+1)$[$*$].

This means if $s = \sup S$ then for any interval $(s - d, s]$ must contain an element of $S$.  And that element must be an integer.  And this must be true no matter how small $d$ is.

But if $d < 1$ then this must be the *only* integer in the interval.  And it *must* exist in *all* such intervals no matter which choice we choose for $d$.

The only point in *all* $(s -d,s]$ is $s$ itself.  So $s$ must be the integer element.

[$*$].  This may have trouble but I believe this is a recursively sound definition of integer:

i) $0$ is an integer.

ii) There are no integers in $(0, 1)$.

iii) $n$ is an integer if and only if $n+1$ is an integer.

Comment: Since $s=\sup S$ there exists $n\in S$ with  $n\in (s-1,s]$ by def'n of $\sup.$..... Now  $n$ is unique  because if $n_1$ and $n_2$ belong to $S\cap (s-1,s]$ then $0< |n_1-n_2|<s-(s-1)=1.$  So you only need (iii) but not (i) and (ii).....................+1

Comment: Funny, that you mention that.  I just made a comment in the op that sort of got me spiralling to that.

Comment: I'm good at simolifying others' answers. My own answers  often use the hardest way to do something easy.

Answer (score 0):

If $a= \sup S$, then $s \leq a$ for all $s \in S$. In particular, $S$ is bounded from above.

Since $|n -m| \geq 1$ for any two different elements $n, \, m \in \mathbb{Z}$, it follows that there exists $\bar{s} \in S$ such that $s \leq \bar{s}$ for all $s \in S$.

By the definition of supremum we have $a \leq \bar{s}$. On the other hand, $\bar{s} \in S$ implies $\bar{s} \leq a$.

So we deduce $a = \bar{s}$ and we are done.