# Supremum of a Subset of Integers is an Integer

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

An non empty subset of integers which is bounded above has a Supremum. How do we prove that Supremum is also an integer? Is my answer correct? :)

Let's take this set as A and Sup A =S.

Let's assume S is a Real number. (S is not an integer)

For all x in A; x<=S , S-1 < S

There exists n which is an element of A greater than S-1 , S-1 < n <= S

1. For all x in A; x<=n. n is an Upper Bound ; S<=n
2. But n is an element of A ; n<=S.

From 1. & 2. S<=n<=n ; n=S

n is an integer. So S is an integer. ; This is a contradiction.

So, our assumption is wrong. Therefore S is an integer.

Comment: This is somewhat of a trivial statement because the "supremum" of such a set must be the maximum and therefore contained within the set.

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2411643/565609) is the formal proof

Comment: thankss @emonHR

Comment: A more direct proof than the one emonHR linked to: "If $S = \sup A$, then there is a greatest integer $n \le S$. Since there are no integers strictly between $n$ and $S$, it must be that $a \le n, \forall a \in A$. i.e., $n$ is an upper bound of $A$ and therefore $S \le n$. Thus $S = n$, an integer.

Comment: @Math1000 - the point of this question is actually proving "the supremum of such a set must be the maximum".